# please explain this piece of python code and how to write equivalent in lisp

Tags: python, common-lisp

Please explain the `[[[0]*64 for i in range(7)] for j in range(2)]` part and how to write a lisp equivalent.

```
pieceHashes = [[[0]*64 for i in range(7)] for j in range(2)]
    for color in WHITE, BLACK:
        for piece in PAWN, KNIGHT, BISHOP, ROOK, QUEEN, KING:
            for cord in range(64):
                pieceHashes[color][piece][cord] = randint(0, maxint)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(let ((piece-array (make-array '(2 7 64) :initial-element 0)))
  (dolist (color `(,white ,black))
    (dolist (piece `(,pawn ,knight ,bishop ,rook ,queen ,king))
      (loop for cord below 64
            do (setf (aref piece-array color piece cord)
                     (random maxint))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It generates a three-dimensional array that has 64 x 7 x 2 elements.
The array is then filled on the final line.

Comment: The code obviously generates random hash values for different types of chess pieces on different locations of the board and stores them in a large array. WHITE, BLACK, PAWN, and so on, are symbolic constants that map to integers. You can use (defconstant WHITE 0) (defconstant BLACK 1) and so on to define the symbolic constants in CL, and (make-array 64 7 2) to create the corresponding array.